# How to test outcome based on the value of useState

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I have a component like this:

```js
const Component = ({callback}) => {

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);


  const increment = () => {
    if(selected) {
      callback()
    } else {
      do something else...
    }
  }

}
```

How can I test that that callback is being called with react testing library and jest?  Everything I'm reading online says you should test the DOM to test state, but I'm not really testing state, I'm testing based on the value of state.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the callback as a prop:

```
const callback = jest.fn()
const { getByText } = render(<Component callback={callback} />)
fireEvent.click(getByText('Submit'))
expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledWith()
```

In the same way, you can tests when `selected` is `false` that `callback` is not called.

Comment: Thanks Giorgio, I am testing that however my test coverage is saying that the lines not covered are those within the if block.

That callback can be called 3 times within the component, on submit like your example above and in two other functions (increment and decrement ) that depend on state being true to call it.

(edited original question with function name update to clarify this response)

Comment: "In the same way, you can tests when selected is false that callback is not called." how would I be able to change selected to false tho? or true, if its set via useState.  This is my issue

Comment: How do you change that in your real app?

Comment: the component is loaded with initial state as false, as shown above and then it will be changed as a toggle like setSelected(!selected)

Comment: Yeah, but how does a user change that?

Comment: setSelected(!selected) is called within handleSubmit

Comment: Thanks for your help, talking this through has just helped me find the solution.  I have to fireEvent on submit, then on increment/decrement

Comment: Yes, exactly that